# curl remove an url

Tags: linux, ubuntu, curl

when i put `sudo apt-get update` i got this

[image]

I want to remove urls with skype and nodejs, i try this but doesn't work

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots as images](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That isn't what cURL is for - or the `DELETE` method either (that is for programming against or implementing a RESTful API).

You need to remove the PPA or other sources.list entry that refers to those repositories.

Look in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the contents of any file in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory.  To disable, simply comment it out.

If you are using the GUI, you can use the "Software Sources" applet.